# Burp Suite - Pixel 2 XL (Android P) can't find a way to certificate using Burp Suite

Tags: android, ssl, burp

So I have been trying to get requests/SSL through burp using my phone. basically I followed these steps very carefully many times:

[Configuring your Browser to work with Burp](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783055-configuring-your-browser-to-work-with-burp)
[Configuring an Android Device to Work With Burp](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp)

I used different ports such as 8888, 8082, 8080 and I also of course change the port in the wi-fi that I use with the computers IP etc *192.168.10.190* - First of all it says on my phone that it couldn't find any network but when I access etc Google, Youtube it works fine. What I then need to do is to get a certification so I can use it as trusted certfication/device

so I followed this one:

[Installing Burp's CA Certificate in an Android Device](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841102-Mobile%20Set-up_Android%20Device%20-%20Installing%20CA%20Certificate.html)

So whenever I try to access **http://burp** to get certification it says *ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED/No response received from remote server* - I tried using http://localhost:8080/ but same issue.

What can I do to make it work so I can see all the requests/SSL through Burp Suite?

To chris:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />

        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a little trick to use the Burp certificate on Android from 4.2 and up.

***Requisite: Install Firefox***

1. Listen on all interfaces

   [image: Proxy Options]
2. Access from you Computer http://127.0.0.1:8080 and download "cert.der" clicking on "CA Certificate" link on Top Right corner

   [image]
3. Open **"Firefox"**, go to Options / Privacy and Security / Certificates.
4. Open **"See certificates"** dialog, go to **"Authorities"**, click **"Import"** and choose the saved **"cert.der"** file.
5. Scroll down to **PortSwigger** Auth, select **"PortSwigger CA"** and click **Export**.
6. Save this file as **"PortSwiggerCA.crt"**
7. Upload this file to your Android Phone
8. Go To Settings
9. Type on search box: "Install from Storage"
10. Select the **"PortSwiggerCA.crt"** file
11. Choose "Apps" not "WI-FI"
12. Go to your Wireless Advanced Settings, use Manual Proxy and point to your Machine local network address.
     Ex.: 192.168.1.200 port 8080
13. Voilá

    [image]

> Obs.: This will not work with Certificate Pinned APK's like Whatsapp
>   and Facebook. You need to tweak them.

Answer (score 0):

The guide seems to be missing instructions regarding networkSecurityConfig which was added in API 24. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

To enable this in debug mode you could add a network_security_config into res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

And then reference this in your manifest by referencing the config file

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    tools:targetApi="24"
```

Comment: Hmm! Im sorry but my experience with Android is very low. Is there any guide or anything that you can provide on how I can do this? Because I have no idea where I add it at all!

I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I assume I add those thing to each of app I have if I understand correctly?

Comment: Within your AndroidManifest.xml file you should have an application declaration - this is where the android:networkSecurityConfig should be applied. The config should be created in the res/xml directory.

Comment: I added a xml. in my post now. I do have this inside my app but it still doesn't work at all. I haven't been able to add a trusted certification which I assume I need to do and that's where I have the problem? I hahve even applied the apk with those network security config but the Burp Suite still won't read it.

Comment: Can the `<network-security-config>` tag be put directly in the manifest ?